# Heroku does not find private NPM package

Tags: reactjs, heroku, npm

UPDATE: Seems the error is related to one of my private packages

I am using a private module for my react app, built with heroku-create-react-app.

this is my `.npmrc` inside the project root folder:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken={NPM_TOKEN}
init.author.name=My.Name
scope=username
@username:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@myname/my-component": "^0.1.9",
    ...
}
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar ./src/ -o ./src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

On heroku I set up the environment variable as
`NPM_TOKEN` and set the token as its value.

When pushing to heroku I get this error:

```
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! code E404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @myname/my-component@https://registry.npmjs.org/@my-name/my-component/-/my-component-0.1.9.tgz
remote:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the GitHub repository named heroku-create-react-app, but if it's bootstrapped using create-react-app, the variable name needs to start with "REACT_APP_" for it to be available under the variable process.env. This post has more information: http://uidevdaily.com/2018/how-to-set-environment-specific-variables-in-a-react-app.